# Problem while reading file from URL - Timeout

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm able to execute below sample code locally (output: 200 OK) but unable to execute (output: timeout) the same code in AWS ec2 server. This code used to work perfectly fine in AWS ec2 until last week, but stoped working since last few days.

```
public class CheckURL {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent("Java Agent").build();
    String urlString = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/DEC/cm26DEC2019bhav.csv.zip";

    try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        System.out.println("Status code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Note: ec2 server connected to Internet Gateway and Inbound/Outbound both are set to All traffic. Interestingly, the above code works perfectly fine with https://google.com as URL in ec2 server. Is this something issue with nseindia.com site?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
```

Comment: You might need to increase timeout values of HttpClient as well as the server.

Comment: Have you tried SSHing to the server and trying to ping this host from there?

Comment: @TomazFernandes the URL h specified in the example is accessible and zip is downloaded. means the machine is accessible over the http.

Comment: @Susovon Pal, I tried your code and its giving me 200 only.

Comment: Yep, but if he can’t ping this host from the EC2 server it means it’s a AWS configuration problem, rather than a java problem...

Comment: Sorry I read the question wrong. Yeah for sure it may be some security group or internet gateway related issue.

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Update: 1. Am able to ping the host (nseindia.com) from ec2 server, so no issue with internet gateway. 2. @SauravKumarSingh - this code is working fine in local but not working in aws ec2. did you try running this code in ec2 server?

Comment: Added stackstrace

Comment: If I replace the nseindia.com URL with https://google.com it works perfectly fine in ec2 server. Not sure why the above code works fine in ec2 server for google.com but not for nseindia.com

Answer (score 1):

Timing out as well when trying this from the command line with `curl`:

```
$ curl -iv https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/DEC/cm26DEC2019bhav.csv.zip
*   Trying 104.90.192.157:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.nseindia.com (104.90.192.157) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IN; ST=Maharashtra; L=Mumbai; O=National Stock Exchange of India Ltd.; OU=IT; CN=www.nseindia.com
*  start date: Dec  6 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 12 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.nseindia.com" matched cert's "www.nseindia.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/DEC/cm26DEC2019bhav.csv.zip HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.nseindia.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
>
* OpenSSL SSL_read: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
```

So there's no problem on your side.